# Store arbitrary characters in Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I'm trying to store some text containing html tags into properties, which doesn't work. I created a form for a property with the data type 'text' and a template. Saving the form writes the text into the template, but it can't get displayed, as it contains illegal characters, as I guess.

What I'm trying to do:

- I need a form to enter data, containing html tags and special
  characters
- I'd like to be able to use a query to find all those pages
  and show that text using a template I provide to the ask query.

I also tried to use the free text option, but then I can't retrieve it using the ask query.

What would be the best, or at least a working solution to this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

storing text with html tags is a bit tricky in SemanticMediaWiki

The reason is the invention of the [StripMarkers UNIQ/QINU](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Strip_marker) by the MediaWiki developers.

When parsing the content of page with html tags in it the parsing is sort of "postponed". This technical detail unfortunately makes it hard for extension developers like the SMW developers to solve the issue of handling such content. Also it makes it hard for lay people to follow the discussion on how to solve the problem

Here are two examples of SMW Issues that are marked as "closed". This state of affairs means that by following the configuration hints in the issue your problem should be solved. If not please ask a question on the SMW issue list or even initiate the reopening of the issues.

- https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/pull/794
- https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/3707

Answer (score 0):

On my wiki we ran into this and resolved it by replacing special characters (we had issues with [ ] =, but the same problem happens with to < > tags too) with alternate unicode characters using [the regex extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Regex_Fun) and a template before setting the property with {{#set:}}. If you want to display the formatted text on the wiki directly then call that parameter separately without replacing the unicode characters.

When you want to display the property, you can then run the reverse replacement with regex before displaying your now intact code (using the [template result format](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Using_templates) to allow you to perform the operation on the output of the query).

To switch to special characters you can create this template

```
{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{{1|}}}|/=/|꞊}}|/\[/|［}}|/\]/|］}}|/>/|≽}}|/</|≼}}
```

And to switch back you can use this as a template

```
{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{#regex:{{{1|}}}|/꞊/|=}}|/［/|[}}|/］/|]}}|/≽/|>}}|/≼/|<}}
```